# Bash: why is this variable not being echoed?

Tags: string, bash, shell, date, unix

So I have the following code:

```
IFS=' ';
            dateArr=(${date[i]});
            monthStr=${dateArr[0]};
            day=${dateArr[1]};
            year=${dateArr[2]};
            case "$monthStr" in
                    "Jan") month="01";;
                    "Feb") month="02";;
                    "Mar") month="03";;
                    "Apr") month="04";;
                    "May") month="05";;
                    "Jun") month="06";;
                    "Jul") month="07";;
                    "Aug") month="08";;
                    "Sep") month="09";;
                    "Oct") month="10";;
                    "Nov") month="11";;
                    "Dec") month="12";;
            esac;

            if [ ${#day} -eq 1 ]
            then
                    day=0$day;
            fi

            dateTemp="$year-$month-$day";
            echo $dateTemp;
```

When I run it, I get output along the following:

```
-11-28
-10-27
-01-11
-01-07
-01-07
```

So you can see it is correctly appending the $month and $day variable, but the $year value isn't being added to the $dateTemp variable. It's weird too, because the $year variable isn't empty, since if I echo that out it gives me the correct year. The sample code is in the format "Jan 1 2016", though I am trying to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD.

If anyone could help me out on this I'd appreciate it.

Cheers!

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$year"|hexdump -C`? Why are you touching `$IFS`?

Comment: It seems the $year contains a `$'\r'` at the end.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/G1D3yKx.png I mean, the $year variable seems to be updating correctly...

Comment: The `0d` in your screen shot is a carriage return.

Comment: See the first suggestion from [before asking about problematic code](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1):

Your value of `year` ends with a carriage return (the `0d` visible in your screen shot). Most terminals "display" a carriage return by moving the cursor to the beginning of the current line, so that the characters that follow it overwrite previously written characters. The quick fix is to remove the carriage return with

```
year=${year%.}
```

The better fix is to remove the carriage returns from the input data used to populate `dateArr`.

Comment: Hmm I tried that and it didn't seem to work. It's not the best solution, but since I know the year value is always 4 digits long, I can just use  year=${dateArr[2]:0:4};

Comment: Did you do that after you set `year` in your code? You can also do it in one line with `year=${dateArr[2]%.}`.

Comment: Yeah I did. I also tried sed which didn't work until I added the -e parameter. That seems like the best option, since then I can just use sed the whole document rather than having to individually code for each variable. Cheers though man :)

Comment: @Noob then if you found the sollution on your own, answer your own post and accept the answer so the people reading this can get help as well by the correct answer, thanks you!